# Flashpoint FP80 / SRAM S80 - rear hub specifications?

Tags: wheels, hub, freehub

I'm looking for the **specs of a SRAM S80 rear wheel hub**. I dearly wish to replace its 9/10-speed freehub body with one that can accomodate Shimano 11-cog casettes.

SRAM S80 was a 80mm-profile aero wheelset for TT/tri (formerly also named FlashPoint FP80, before SRAM acquired Zipp). Its rear hub bears no ID or name and given the wheels' age, I can find no trace of it on the internet, so if anyone here knows... I'm all ears. But the hub does look conventional enough that I'm hoping I could source a compatible 11-speed freehub body (spline) for replacement.

Alternatives (and why I don't like them):

1. Manual widening (shaving off the spline flange) - difficult even with the right tools, and more importantly, the derailleur might end up too close to the spokes. Risky idea.
2. Campy freehub + Campy 11-sp. casette - Campy 11-speed casettes fit 9/10-speed Campy splines (and the latter is available as a replacement part), but buying both is as expensive as buying a completely new hub and relacing the rim. Plus, shifting with a Shimano derailleur is said not be 100% accurate, despite the cross-compatibility.

Rationale: I'm buying a budget road bike, which I'd like to make a bit more TT-friendly (aero bars and wheels), and I already have the S80 rear wheel after a relative of mine. But I don't want to buy a 10-speed drivetrain just so I can use the wheel, so...

Comment: Why wouldn't you consider 10-speed, especially on a non-optimised "budget" bike? You can probably find a new-old-stock or lightly-used Ultegra 6700 groupset at a very reasonable price. Dura-Ace 7900 bar-end shifters are also widely available, if required. As and when you 'outgrow' the bike, It'll still retain some significant value and can be sold on complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SRAM S60 wheel uses a SRAM built hub, designed in 2010 for the [S-30 and S-60 wheels](https://sram-cdn-pull-zone-gsdesign.netdna-ssl.com/cdn/farfuture/G4Pa7mar2FMqTDHghIfrENO95Gf3G9xxZeFPi4t_1zY/mtime:1372788163/sites/default/files/techdocs/sram_s30_s27_wheel_service_manual.pdf) called the S-30 Comp.

It is not 11 speed compatible, and they never made an alternative freehub for it.

Instead, they came out with the Zipp 30 and 60 wheels, which had 11 speed options, and discontinued the SRAM S-Series wheels.

I agree with you that modifying the freehub is a bad idea. SRAM & Zipp Road wheels already have spoke clearance issues with the cassette, especially the Zipp 303 FC. Better to sell that wheel, and buy something compatible.

As an alternative, look at getting a Campy splined cassette which is spaced for Shimano 11 speed.  Miche used to make one, but they are hard to come by.

Comment: "Better to sell that wheel, and buy something compatible." - true, actually. What I didn't realize (until I rode them on a different bike - I also have an S60 front) is that the whole wheelset is **really** heavy (post-ride weigh-in at >2kg), which is OK for training on total flats, but pretty underwhelming everywhere else. Bottom line - not worth it. (I just regret wasting your time, sorry for that.)

Answer (score 2):

The hub on SRAM S40/60/80 uses a Reynolds freehub.  This freehub body will upgrade it to 11speed.  http://www.jensonusa.com/Reynolds-11-Speed-Freehub-Body/
This freehub comes with new endcaps.  The non drive side is slightly longer and the drive side is slightly shorter.  To avoid having to redish your wheel you may need to use the old caps or just use the the drive side cap side cap

I have heard the Reynold KT 11 speed freehub will also work but I have no personal experience with this.  This freehub is extremely hard to come by in the States, UK has greater availability.

Answer (score 1):

I recently received a pair s80/s60 and I’m currently riding on chorus 11s groupset. I can confirm that the Reynolds freehub in the link works very fine, it’s a perfect fit for the Sram hub. I guess it’s the same compatibility with shimano 11 s. 
Thank you very much for the info and the links, helped me a lot.
Btw, it was about 80€ bought in Europe.